# generate UUID of long type

Tags: java, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Please give me sample code to generate `UUID` of `long` type in java without using timestamp.

Thanks

Comment: A UUID represents a 128-bit value. That is not going to fit in a `long`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique serial number in a java web application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519288/unique-serial-number-in-a-java-web-application)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A real UUID is 128 bits.  A long is 64 bits.

This is not just pedantry.  UUID stands for **Universal** Unique IDentifier.

The "universal uniqueness" of the [established UUID schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid) are based on:

- encoding a MAC address and a timestamp,
- encoding a hash of a DNS name and a timestamp, or
- using a 122 bit random number ... which is large enough that the probability of a collision is very very small.

With 64 bits, there are simply not enough bits for "universal uniqueness".  For instance, the birthday paradox means that if we had a number of computers generating random 64 bit numbers, the probability of a potentially detectable collision would be large enough to be of concern.

Now if you just want a UID (not a UUID), then any 64-bit sequence generator will do the job, provided that you take steps to guard against the sequence repeating.  (If the sequence repeats, then the IDs are not unique in time; i.e. over time a given ID may denote different entities.)

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at [java.util.UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a simple unique long you can use AtomicLong.incrementAndGet(). This doesn't use a timestamp but does reset to 0 every time you start it and is not unique across JVMs.

What is the requirement not to use timestamps all about? UUID uses a timestamp. (amoungst other things)

Comment: Some UUID types use timestamps, some use other means to get uniqueness.

Comment: @StephenC Good point. I didn't realise there are 4 documented ways to generate a UUID.