# DB2 BIGINT id generator

Tags: java, db2, uuid

I have the following class loaded into DB2 9.7.4 Express-C for generating ids for rows

```
public class Int64UUID {

    public static final long dx =  30*386*12*30*24*3600*1000; // starting at 2000 year
    public static long lastUUID = System.currentTimeMillis() - dx;

    public static synchronized long random(){
        long uuid = System.currentTimeMillis() - dx;
        while(uuid == lastUUID)
            uuid = System.currentTimeMillis() - dx;
        lastUUID = uuid;
        return uuid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Int64UUID.random());
    }

}
```

and the following function for using it

```
CREATE FUNCTION "MYSCHEMA"."INT64_GUID" ( )
  RETURNS BIGINT
  SPECIFIC "SQL110520165927000"
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME 'Int64UUID.random'
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  NO SQL
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  DISALLOW PARALLEL;
```

Will ids generated using these function be unique across db2 sessions due to synchronization, and is these a better alternative to GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, I know that those id's will expire in next 60 years but 60 years is long period

Answer (score 1):

These IDs will likely not be unique.  If you have two sessions in different JVMs generating IDs at the same time millisecond resolution is not large enough to ensure you will get unique IDs.

Consider using the built in `UUID`. However, this will produce a 128 bit UUID.  But it ensures uniqueness even across sessions, even in different JVMs.

There is another stack overflow discussion which addresses how to
[generate UUID of long type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529727/generate-uuid-of-long-type) .

Comment: yes but why will I have two JVM's in different sessions on one DB2 Instance?

Comment: You might be right, but I am not sure how DB2 manages the JVM per session.  However, next thing you will need to worry about is how your code has the possibility to block for 1 millisecond (in the while) each time it needs to generate an ID.  The proper UUID functions mentioned do not have this problem.

Comment: yes but 1 millisecond is so irrelevant in my project, i assume that average generate uuid requests per second won't be more than 10

Answer (score 1):

I use GENERATE_UNIQUE with a  trigger ON INSERT for the table

[IBM DB2 - GENERATE_UNIQUE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000809.htm)

Here's an article on developerworks called [Generating universally unique identifiers (UUID)](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/generating_universally_unique_identifiers_uuid63?lang=en)
which may help?

Comment: I know about that but i have a requirement to have Id's as BIGINT and not Character(13) for bit data

Answer (score 0):

You `dx` value looks a bit random.  It is too large to fit in an `int` and will over flow but it also doesn't appear correct.  You have 30 * (30 years) * 386 (not sure if this is supposed to be 356) * 12 (months per year) * 30 (days in a typical month)

Comment: its long (64 bit int) and yea you are right about days but it's irrelevant in the context of the question