# Is there any way to generate UUID of type Int64 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, uuid

I know we can generate UUID in iOS using

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

But this is a string, right? I want to use this to generate Id in my Core Data table, so I like to generate an Integer UUID for fast searching (Integer searching is faster than string searching in SQLite right?)

The easy way I saw is:

```
uuid.hashValue
```

But will that will be unique always?

I found this for java [generate UUID of long type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530059/901715)

Is this same for iOS? And I may not want that much uniqueness, just enough to prevent collision between 2, 3 devices.

Comment: A UUID is 128 bits. Yes, `uuidString` is a string. `hashValue` is not unique and it can change every time you run the app.

Comment: oh ok, I don't need to generate hash value with the same UUID twice, once I added that to the database I can refer that like an Id ID.

Comment: As far as performance, the way to improve that is by adding an index, as explained in [the WWDC 2018 Core Data video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/224/).  Since you've got Core Data on top of SQLite, performance trends may not be as you expect for SQLite.

Comment: Instead of adding your own UUID, consider using NSManagedObject.objectID (although there is a drawback to that, see *Important* in its documentation).

Comment: @JerryKrinock ok, I thought of using that first, but my requirement is to transfer the same data to another device, I am trying to create a UUID which will be valid for both device

Comment: @rmaddy are you saying `uuidString` is unique but `hashValue` is not?

Comment: @Eldhose, regarding objectID, if you mean you are transferring the Core Data sqlite file to another device, the other device *shall* get the same object ID.  Quote from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectid): _A managed object ID uniquely identifies the same managed object both between managed object contexts in a single application, and in multiple applications (as in distributed systems)._

Comment: @Eldhose Yes. A UUID by definition is unique across time, apps, and devices. Any value's `hashValue` is in no way guaranteed to be unique, ever. Two unique UUIDs could have the same hash. A string and some custom class could have the same hash, etc.

Comment: @JerryKrinock, thanks for the info I was not aware of that, but in my app, I am passing data to another device through service. so the data is recreated.

Comment: @rmaddy , ok, so it seems not safe to use Int64 . So I am going to settile for indexed uid string

Answer (score -1):

You can create NSMutableData object from NSUUID with this code:

```
let uid = NSUUID.UUID()

// data object with size
let data = NSMutableData(length: 16)

// fill the bytes from the uuid
myUuid.getUUIDBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer(data.mutableBytes))
```